# Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from? Why showing this error?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, sdk

```
Downloading Darwin x64 Dart SDK from Flutter engine <<<<<<< HEAD
ffe7b86a1e5b5cb63c8385ae1adc759e372ee8f4
=======
c08d7d5efc9aa6eb3c30cfb3be6dc09bca5e7631
>>>>>>> eb6d86ee27deecba4a83536aa20f366a6044895c...
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
/Applications/Development/flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.sh: line 156: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/<<<<<<< HEAD
ffe7b86a1e5b5cb63c8385ae1adc759e372ee8f4
=======
c08d7d5efc9aa6eb3c30cfb3be6dc09bca5e7631
>>>>>>> eb6d86ee27deecba4a83536aa20f366a6044895c/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
  https://flutter.dev/community/china

exit code 1
```

Comment: It sounds like you have some kind of merge conflict in your Flutter SDK.  Did you (perhaps inadvertently) make changes to it?    Perhaps try doing `git reset --hard` from your Flutter SDK directory first to discard any changes to it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).